# synching a team provisioning profile to an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have a test version of an app on my phone which has stopped working last week when its team provisioning profile expired. The profile is now update in Xcode and on the developer portal but not yet on the phone. Is there any way of forcing an update on the phone which our reinstalling the app and overwriting its [slightly changed Core Data] data store?

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up your core data version correctly, it should not overwrite the data store.  If you are currently developing it, and the core data data store version hasn't been incremented, can you not increment the version to force iOS to migrate the data to the new structure?

Barring that, you have 2 or 3 options to install it, depending on how the profile is set up.

If you are using a wildcard app ID in your provisioning profile, you can get the new version onto the phone by simply creating a new dummy app (or use one of Apple's sample apps) and sign it with the new profile / cert.  This will get the new profile onto the device without touching the existing app (just make sure you don't use the same bundle ID for the dummy app.

If you have an explicit app ID, you can try to add the provisioning profile manually through the Xcode Devices window. Right click on the device on the left and select "Show provisioning profiles..." In the window with the provisioning profiles, click the little "+" below the list, browse to your provisioning profile and open it.  If it is valid for the device, it will get added on the device.

Finally, if you have MDM (Mobile Device Management) managing the device, you can use that to push the profile to the device.

Once you get the profile on the device, you should be able to run the app again.

Unfortunately, Apple no longer allows you to simply email the provisioning profile to the email account on the device and let the user open it.  I believe starting with iOS 8 you haven't been able to do that and you need to install it either with an app, through Xcode, or with MDM.